# Map export to PDF is exporting some features but not others using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, pdf

I am trying to export a map with the exact same settings as I always do, but it is choosing not to export the more complicated features such as contours, water and our vegetation inventory while successfully exporting roads, annotation and all the layout components. The problem does not seem to be confined to a certain geometry type. I get the same result no matter the format or settings. Some of the data is on a local server while most of it is from a shared corporate server.

The main culprit is probably the fact that I'm using Data Driven Pages, but I get the same result when I turn them off.

Any ideas?

It's not even attempting to export them as it completes in a few seconds while normally I would expect it to take longer. I unfortunately do not have any graphics programs to mess around with.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adjusting the order of different map layers. One layer of my map didn't show up on the exported map was because it was covered the by another layer, while I didn't notice any difference on ArcMap. I simply send the layer to the front (in the layout view, **right click** the layer that doesn't show up when exporting, then click **Order**, choose **Bring to Front**). You may need to do more adjustment to the order of different layers in order to have all layers displayed properly.